# Unable to carry edited data to DB in jqgrid inline editing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I'm developing a web based application using bootstrap.
I'm trying to implement inline editing in my grid on page load but when I click on edit button on the grid, all the cells become editable text and later i click on save button it shows the text I am typing in the particular cell.but on the onclick of save button i unable to call a function which performs updation of data in DB.

**Here is my code :**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var GetUrl = Web_Path + '/Test/TestHandler/GetTestData/' + AjaxHandlerName;

                jQuery("#jqGrid-container").jqGrid({
                    url: GetUrl,
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    postData: { SearchInfo: function () { return getSearchPostData() } },
                    colNames: [' ', 'ID', 'Name', 'ContactNo', 'EmpId', 'MailId', 'RoleName'],
                    colModel: [
                    { name: 'myac', index: '', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false,
                        formatter: 'actions',
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            delOptions: { recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback }
                        }
                    },
                                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, editable: true },
                                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', validation: { required: true }, sortable: true, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "40", maxlength: "50"} },
                                { name: 'ContactNo', index: 'ContactNo', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30"} },
                                { name: 'EmpId', index: 'EmpId', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "20", maxlength: "30"} },
                                { name: 'MailId', index: 'MailId', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { size: "40", maxlength: "50"} },
 {name: 'RoleName', index: 'RoleName', sortable: false }
  ],
                    jsonReader: {
                        id: 'Id',
                        repeatitems: false
                    },
                    height: "100%",
                    pager: '#jqGrid-pager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: 'Id',
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "JQ grid data",
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        var table = this;
                        updatePagerIcons(table);                       
                    }
                });
});

 function getSearchPostData() {
            var searchData = {};
            searchData.Id=1;

            return JSON.stringify(searchData);
        }
 function updatePagerIcons(table) {
            var replacement =
                    {
                        'ui-icon-seek-first': 'icon-double-angle-left bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'icon-angle-left bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-next': 'icon-angle-right bigger-140',
                        'ui-icon-seek-end': 'icon-double-angle-right bigger-140'
                    };
            $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));

                if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
            })
}

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">           
            <table id="jqGrid-container" class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            </table>
            <div id="jqGrid-pager">
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have used **jquery.jqGrid.min.js**.

when i try to save, unable to carry the data to DB.. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `editurl` properties of jqgrid which basically is the controller URL of your server. When save action is triggered , `editurl` is called upon.

While calling `editurl` following data is sent to the server according to [jqgrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) ,

**How is the data organized**

When the row is edited and the input elements are created we set the following rules:

- the table row becomes attribute editable=“1”
- the array savedRow (option in the grid) is filled with the values
  before the editing. This is a name:value pair array with additional
  pair id:rowid
- Hidden fields are not included
- The id of the editable element is constructed as 'rowid_'+ the name
  from the colModel array. Example if we edit row with id=10 and the
  only editable element is 'myname' (from colModel) then the id becomes
  10_myname.
- The name of the editable element is constructed from the name of the
  colModel array - property - name after the row is saved or restored
  the editable attribute is set to “0” and the savedRow item with
  id=rowid is deleted

**What is posted to the server?**

When the data is posted to the server we construct an object {} that contain(s):

- the name:value pair where the name is the name of the input element
  represented in the row (this is for all input elements)
- additionally we add a pair id:rowid where the rowid is the id of the
  row
- if the extraparam parameter is not empty we extend this data with the
  posted data

So, you need to setup the Server side to get the value sent from the jqGrid on edit/save action.